# infinite loop. anyone have any ideas?

Tags: java

```
public int sum (int num1, int num2){
    int sum = 0;
        if(num2>num1){
        for (int i = num1; i<=num2; i++){
            sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        else{
        for (int i = num2; i <= num1; i++){
            sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("The sum between " +num1+ " and " +num2+ " equals " + sum);
    return sum(num1, num2);
    }
}
```

infinite loop problem. any fixes?
trying to find the sum of all the numbers between two inputs. this is the class definition any ideas?

Comment: There's no exit case for the recursive call...

Comment: Format your code legibly. Then, only have one version of the loop. Specify that the caller needs to provide the lower number first, and then provide another method that you can call that will swap them around if necessary, so that your code is simpler and easier to follow.

Comment: Hello, Follow coding standards.Same name for variable and function. unacceptable. @chrylis : thanks dude.

Comment: Yes, use a debugger and you could find out yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `sum()` again, and without any condition to check when to break the recursion. Hence an infinite loop

As the other answers have pointed out, you have to replace `return sum(num1,num2);` with `return sum;`

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate the quick response

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help :-) @CaseyButo

Answer (score 2):

In place of return `sum(num1, num2)`; you should `return sum;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public int sum (int num1, int num2)
{
   int sum = 0;
   if(num2>num1)
   {
        for (int i = num1; i<=num2; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
         }
   }
   else
   {
        for (int i = num2; i <= num1; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The sum between " +num1+ " and " +num2+ " equals " + sum);
    return sum;  
  }
```

you were doing recursive calling thats the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function recursively by `return sum(num1, num2);`. So change  `return sum(num1, num2);` to `return sum;`